# Why is the approximation symbol used in universal algebra?

Tags: notation, approximation, universal-algebra

Why is the approximation symbol "$\approx$" used in universal algebra instead of "is equal to" symbol?

**Example:** Bergman´s book "Universal Algebra: Fundamentals and Selected Topics ":

[image]

**Edit**: Found some explanation in the book, still not so clear to me though.
[image]

Comment: For what it's worth, Wikipedia's ["Universal algebra" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_algebra) uses "$=$".

Comment: It's explained at the bottom of that page in that book!

Comment: By the way, you should perhaps have mentioned that the book is *Universal Algebra: Fundamentals and Selected Topics* by Clifford Bergman, as opposed to, for example, *An Invitation to General Algebra and Universal Constructions* by George M. Bergman...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about Bergman, but Burris & Sankappanavar: [*A Course in Universal Algebra*](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Esnburris/htdocs/UALG/univ-algebra.pdf) has this to say on page 3:

> The symbol “$=$” is used to express the fact that both sides name the same object, whereas “$\approx$” is used to build equations which may or may not be true of particular elements. (A careful study of $\approx$ is given in Chapter II.)

Comment: Don´t you have the symbols switched? I thought the equality symbol is tru for some variables, while the identity is just.. True, no matter what.

Comment: No, that's exactly how B&S explain the symbols. (If you are in doubt, see it yourself by following the link!)

Comment: @TerezaTizkova No, it's not switched at all. But B&S allow the general case that the "identity for all" doesn't hold in a certain domain. But then they can still talk about the commutative law as $x \cdot y \approx y \cdot x$, even when it doesn't hold. "Laws" as objects in their own right, as it were.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma That is strange, since in my question´s screenshot, Bergman says that the $\approx$ asserts the equality for all, no the $=$.

Comment: @TerezaTizkova Why not just accept that $\approx$ is about "laws" and $=$ about identities or equations?